# Haskell heterogeneous list of Storable objects

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, existential-type, heterogeneous

I want to write function that can poke heterogeneous list of Storable objects (different types)

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ExistentialQuantification, ImpredicativeTypes #-}

pokeMany :: Ptr b -> Int -> [forall a. Storable a => a] -> IO ()
pokeMany _ _ [] = return ()
pokeMany ptr offset (x:xs) = do
    pokeByteOff ptr offset x
    pokeMany ptr (offset + sizeOf x) xs

somePoke :: Ptr a -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
somePoke ptr x1 x2 = pokeMany ptr 0 [x1, x2]
```

But I get compile errors:

```
No instance for (Storable a1) arising from a use of `sizeOf'
The type variable `a1' is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Storable CChar -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Storable CClock -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'
  instance Storable CDouble -- Defined in `Foreign.C.Types'

Couldn't match expected type `a2' with actual type `Int'
  `a2' is a rigid type variable bound by
       a type expected by the context: Storable a2 => a2
```

and others ...

Then I create some data type

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ExistentialQuantification, ImpredicativeTypes #-}

data AnyStorable = forall a. Storable a => AnyStorable a

pokeMany :: Ptr b -> Int -> [AnyStorable] -> IO ()
pokeMany _ _ [] = return ()
pokeMany ptr offset (AnyStorable x:xs) = do
    pokeByteOff ptr offset x
    pokeMany ptr (offset + sizeOf x) xs

somePoke :: Ptr a -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
somePoke ptr n c = pokeMany ptr 0 [AnyStorable n, AnyStorable c, AnyStorable 'a']
```

The code above hasn't any compile errors.

Can I write `pokeMany` function without creating new data type like AnyStorable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. What you'd need for that would be `exists` keyword to specify the signature of the function that'll be mapped on the collection. Using `forall` in the datatype effectively expresses the same from the other side.

BTW, you might consider making `AnyStorable` an instance of `Storable`.

Comment: Of course, you are right. `AnyStorable` must be an instance of `Storable`.